# mysql docker container exited with code 1

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to run mysql on windows using docker container when i try use docker-compose up command on docker-compose file this the result.

```
> D:\dockerfiles>docker-compose up
db_1  | Initializing database
db_1  | 2018-10-08T09:00:29.024081Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
db_1  | 2018-10-08T09:00:29.024224Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
db_1  | 2018-10-08T09:00:29.024512Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1  | 2018-10-08T09:00:29.028590Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
db_1  | 2018-10-08T09:00:29.028673Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
db_1  |
dockerfiles_db_1 exited with code 1
```

and this my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: star
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```

update of docker compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_con1
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    command: --disable-partition-engine-check
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: star
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - samplenet
networks:
  samplenet:
    driver: nat
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure that code blocks are surrounded by `{` and `}` for readability.

Comment: See https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/290.

Comment: GitHub solution dose not work

Comment: Problem with `- "./:/var/lib/mysql"` is, current directory (`./`) is not empty.  It contains docker-compose file.

Comment: i change '"./:/var/lib/mysql "' to " ./data" and the same error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some files in `/var/lib/mysql` directory.  Remove everything from this directory.
Or highly recommended, use volumes in `docker-compose.yml`.

```
volumes:
  - /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```

Update:
I tested with the following compose file, it worked fine without any errors.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: star
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```

Comment: sorry for my little information but what is /my/own/datadir and /var/lib/mysql

Comment: `/my/own/datadir` is path where you want to store database files on your host machine & `/var/lib/mysql` is the path where mysql stores them in container.

Comment: But mysql Dockerfile adds default mount point `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql`, which instructs mysql container to store database files in `/var/lib/mysql` directory on host machine.

Comment: be sure to remove existing failed containers.  you can use `docker-compose down`.

Comment: I do that and also delete old volumes

Comment: I just noticed that you are using windows machine.  It seems like volume mount is not working, docker is still using default mount path.  Checkout this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4303.

Comment: thanks for your answers but this error appear 
`ERROR: for test8_db_1 Cannot create container for service db: invalid volume specification: '/d/test8/data:/var/lib/mysql:rw' ERROR: for db Cannot create container for service db: invalid volume specification: '/d/test8/data:/var/lib/mysql:rw' ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: Please see docker documentation for how to specify volumes in windows environment.

Answer (score 3):

For those who ran the container using the `docker run` command and added the `--detach|-d` flag; Remove and rerun the container without the `-d` flag.

This should provide the error message to why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behaviour defining restaart=always, If I remove it everything went fine, and later I run command

```
docker update --restart=always {{ID OF CONTAINER}}
```

Which makes it restart always. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Update Volume in docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```

Update: this compose file, it worked fine .

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
```